# Does java provide a clean mechanism for ensuring thread shutdown logic runs when thread dies?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm wondering why there seems to be no support for thread level 'shutdown hooks', which run when a specific thread terminates; *not* when the JVM terminates.

So lets say someone wrote a simple thread with a run method with sudo code like this (intentionally leaving out thread interrupt here for now...):

```
 public void run(){

    SeverSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(port);

    while(!isStopRequested){
        Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();

        processRequest(socket);
    }

    runShutdownLogic();
 }

 public void stopServer(){

     isStopRequested=false;

     //interrupt thread potentially, see below
 }
```

This thread could die in a few ways:

1. someone calls stopServer, followed by either...

   a. the serversocket.accept accepting one last socket and returning

   b. an interrupt sent to intterupt serverSocket.accept
2. an exception is thrown
3. Someone kills the thread, directly or through executor service.
4. The JVM goes down.

In any of these cases we want to run the shutdownLogic method, lets say it does something more then just close the seversocket, some interface with an external source that is important to do no matter how the thread shuts down.

As I understand it this is not very easy to do, in fact it seems hard enough that I feel I must be missing some basic threading feature.  the 1a case is simple and works as is.  1b case works so long as the developer doesn't swallow interruptExceptions, something that is done way to often but is easy enough to avoid if you know what an interrupt exception is.

In case of an exception you need to move the shutdown method into a finally block.

In cases 3 & 4 though this gets harder.  For 3 I think threads can be killed 'nicely', with an interrupt that one can catch, check to see it's a sigkill, and then force an exit of the code, but this requires even more intelligent handling of a InterruptException that most improperly swallow; plus would get ugly fast if this check has to be done in dozens of locations that can through interrupts.  You can't do much for a hard kill, but no one expects proper shutdown logic for a hard kill so that's fine.

For a JVM shutdown...I don't actually know the exact method the threads are killed.  I assume a sigkill is sent to the threads with a timeout before a hard kill, I'd have to research it more.  If you want to be safe you can add a shutdown hook, but there is no gaurentee of order that shutdown hooks are run and trying to add shutdown hooks for each thread requires careful writing of the hooks to ensure you don't stall or stop the JVM shutdown with a deadlock or unexpected exception in the hook....

If instead of a thread like the one above I have a thread with a finite, but potentially long, processing time, without any waits, it gets even harder since I can't listen for an interrupted exception to know that I need to give up on my threads processing and run the shutdown logic immediately.

Basically, it seems like different method is needed to handle each manner a thread can execute, and needs to be done with every thread.  And still in the case of high CPU threads without waits I still don't now how to gaurente a proper shutdown occurs if the thread (not the whole JVM) is killed midway through...

Is there not a simpler solution to all of this?  For instance the equivalent of a thread level shutdown hook which will run when that specific thread is being killed, regardless of how it dies; even if JVM itself is not shutting down?  Is there some reason a thread level shutdownhook is not possible or dangerous to support, assuming that such doesn't exist.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html

Answer (score 2):

At least one of the reasons is that there really is not a safe and clean mechanism, which is also why [Thread.stop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) is deprecated. By creating a (seemingly) simple mechanism for it, people might think that it's a simple issue and use it wildly.

The same issue exists for finalizers and shutdownhooks. They're not reliable, so it's not a good idea to let developers think that it's a normal tool that they're supposed to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java provides such a mechanism.  Simply use a try/finally construction in your `run()` method, either in your `Thread` subclass or in your `Runnable` if you are using a `Runnable`:

```
public void run() {

    try {
        doBody()
    }
    finally {
        doThreadShutdown()
    }
}
```

This should take care of all of the cases that you are looking for, including normal shutdown of the virtual machine, since the virtual machine shuts down only after all nondaemon threads exit.  Exceptions would be hard stop of the thread, hard kill of the virtual machine, or if the thread is a daemon thread and the virtual machine exits.